# Error after trying to install an extension in Magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, error

There has been an error processing your request

> Error in file:
>   "/home/khankesa/public_html/app/code/local/Ax/Zoom/sql/axzoom_setup/install-1.4.0.php"
>   - PHP "Ioncube loader" is not installed on this server. Please install this extension before installing AJAX-ZOOM; if you encounter any other
>   issues please check troubleshooting section at
>   http://www.ajax-zoom.com/index.php?cid=modules&module=magento and
>   contact AJAX-ZOOM support at
>   http://www.ajax-zoom.com/index.php?cid=contact

Trace:

```
#0 /home/khankesa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/khankesa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.4.3')
#2 /home/khankesa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.4.3')
#3 /home/khankesa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/khankesa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/khankesa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/khankesa/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/khankesa/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Above is the list of errors I got when I tried to install the extension.

Please help to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the IonCube Loader in your system. This modules code is encrypted - this means you need a 3rd party module in your PHP Libraries to get this running. Ask your hosting provider for more details or install the ionCube Loader.

Check http://www.ioncube.com/ for more details.

Comment: What if I wish to remove this too instead of installing another. I mean if I wish not to install any extension that I tried and failed. Quickest way tl get my site back??

Comment: Remove the modules XML in `app/etc/modules/Vendor_Namespace.xml`. Please don't forget to mark the most correct answer as helpful!